# Como listar todos os dados do JSONArray usando JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Estou com dificuldades em listar todos os dados do `JsonArray` em uma *JSF*, sempre fica somente o ultimo valor, já quando uso `System.out.println(variavel)` eu consigo listar tudo sem problemas.

Página *JSF* que precisa receber os dados

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"

      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>DashBoard</h:head><br/><br/>


<h:body>
<h:form >
    <h:outputFormat value="#{ethermine.workers.worker}"/>



   <h:commandButton  value="Iniciar" action="#{ethermine.executar}"/>


</h:form>

</h:body>



</html>
```

Classe responsável pela conversão do JsonArray para objeto:

```
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import json.org.JSONArray;
import json.org.JSONObject;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;

@Model
public class Ethermine {


    private final Workers workers = new Workers();

    private  Conexao conexao = new Conexao();


    public void executar()
    {

    convertJsonForObject(conexao.getJson());


    }

    private void convertJsonForObject(StringBuilder json) {


        JSONObject obj;

        obj = new JSONObject(json.toString());

        JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");

        for(int i = 0; i< jArray.length(); i++){

            JSONObject obj_array_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


            System.out.println(obj_array_data.get("worker"));

            workers.setWorker(String.valueOf(obj_array_data.get("worker")));
        }

    }

    public Workers getWorkers() {
        return workers;
    }
}
```

Classe responsável pela conexão e ter o retorno do JSON:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


 class Conexao {

     private StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder();

     StringBuilder getJson(){


        String address = "https://api.ethermine.org/miner/0940f5fAEF2bba7e1e6288E4bc4E9c75ee334b97/workers";


       System.setProperty("http.agent","chrome");

        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);

            try {
                URLConnection conne = url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = conne.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(inReader);

                String result;


                while((result = out.readLine()) !=null){

                    this.resultado = resultado.append(result);

                    }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return resultado;
    }

}
```

Classe que contém os getters e setters :

```
    public class Workers {

        private Boolean status;
        private String worker;
        private double reportedHashrate;
        private double currentHashrate;
        private Integer validShare;
        private Integer staleShares;
        private Double averageHashrate;


        public void setStatus(Boolean status){

            this.status = status;


        }

        public Boolean getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public String getWorker() {
            return worker;
        }

        public void setWorker(String worker) {
            this.worker = worker;
        }

        public double getReportedHashrate() {
            return reportedHashrate;
        }

        public void setReportedHashrate(double reportedHashrate) {
            this.reportedHashrate = reportedHashrate;
        }

        public double getCurrentHashrate() {
            return currentHashrate;
        }

        public void setCurrentHashrate(double currentHashrate) {
            this.currentHashrate = currentHashrate;
        }



   public Integer getValidShare() {
        return validShare;
    }

    public void setValidShare(Integer validShare) {
        this.validShare = validShare;
    }

    public Integer getStaleShares() {
        return staleShares;
    }

    public void setStaleShares(Integer staleShares) {
        this.staleShares = staleShares;
    }

    public Double getAverageHashrate() {
        return averageHashrate;
    }

    public void setAverageHashrate(Double averageHashrate) {
        this.averageHashrate = averageHashrate;
    }
}
```

Quando executa, fica:

```
DashBoard

Kappauni3
```

Só que na verdade, tem que aparecer:

```
Kappauni1
Kappauni2
Kappauni3
```

Igual na saída do `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, dá uma olhada nesse trecho do seu código:

```
JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");
   for(int i = 0; i< jArray.length(); i++){
      JSONObject obj_array_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
      System.out.println(obj_array_data.get("worker"));
...
```

Quando você ler os dados, você ler de um *array*. Para conseguir adicionar todos os dados lidos você tem que adicioná-los antes em um *array* também

Nesse trecho do seu código:

```
workers.setWorker(String.valueOf(obj_array_data.get("worker")));
```

Só esta sendo enviado o último item do *jArray*.

O que você tem que fazer é algo do tipo:

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i = 0 ; i < jArray.length() ; i++){
    lista.add(jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("worker"));
}
```

Dessa forma você consegue adicionar todos os itens do arquivo *Json*